# I need to contain all matches of a Regex into a text file; I'm new to java programming

Tags: java, regex, file-io

I'm trying to contain all matches found into a text document, I have been banging my head on my desk for the past 3 hours and figured it would be time I asked for help.

My current issue is with the `List<String>` and I'm not sure if it because the information entered is wrong or if it's my file print methods. It does not print to file and with other means of printing such as `writer.println(returnvalue)` and even then, it still only displays one of the matches and not all, I do have the matches appearing in console just to make sure they are showing and they are.

Edit2: Sorry this would be my first question on stackoverflow, I guess my question is How would you print all the data from a  list array to a text file?

Edit3: My newest problem is printing out all matches i am currently stuck printing out the last match, any advice?

```
public static void RegexChecker(String TheRegex, String line){
  String Result= "";
  List<String> returnvalue = new ArrayList<String>();
  Pattern checkRegex = Pattern.compile(TheRegex);
  Matcher regexMatcher = checkRegex.matcher(line);
  int count = 0 ;

  FileWriter writer = null;
  try {
    writer = new FileWriter("output.txt");
  } catch (IOException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
  } 

  while ( regexMatcher.find() ){
    if (regexMatcher.group().length() != 0){
      returnvalue.add(regexMatcher.group());
      System.out.println( regexMatcher.group().trim() );
    }

    for(String str: returnvalue) {
      try {
        out.write(String.valueOf(returnvalue.get(i)));
        writer.write(str);
      } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: Hey Joel, please let us know what's happening and what you expect to happen.  Also, for your benefit and ours, please indent your code following a style something like this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style#Variant:_1TBS.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 2):

Get the `for` out of `while`. You want to write to the file only after all matches have been added to the list. The `for-each` block needs some modifications as well.

The `for-each` construct gives you values from iteration over the collection. You need not obtain the values again using an index.

Try this:

```
while (regexMatcher.find()) {
    if (regexMatcher.group().length() != 0) {
        returnvalue.add(regexMatcher.group());
        System.out.println(regexMatcher.group().trim());
    }
}
try {
    for (String str : returnvalue) {
        writer.write(str + "\n");
    }
    writer.flush();
    writer.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Thanks! this would be a step in the right direction, now i just need to find out how to make the rest of the array show instead of just the last match.(unless of course its not the array but rather what is fed into it.)